# File conversion and deletion on Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, ffmpeg

I’ve got some 90 000 `.m4a` audio recordings, all grouped in various sub-folders depending on their purpose. I want to convert each one to `.wav` and then delete the original `.m4a` after successful conversion. For reasons beyond my control I’m doing this on a Windows machine with limited capacity. I need to delete as I go along, because I don’t have the space to keep both versions.

I have the locations of all files stored, and can easily generate a batch file to do conversion and deletion using `ffmpeg` and DEL iteratively (which is a solution I’ve seen suggested in several places). But is there a way to check that the conversion has been successful before deleting? I really don’t fancy losing the data by accident.

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but: have you considered a backup (on an external device, if there is not enough space on your computer)?

Comment: I have the data backed up but would prefer to avoid having to use the backup. I was hoping for a local solution.

Comment: check `ffmpeg` documentation, if there is some sort of "verify" switch, if you can rely on `%errorlevel%` and if there are any success or error messages, you could parse.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a perfect check to make sure everything worked, but you can use something like this to make sure the target file exists and contains at least a few bytes:

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem configuration values, toconvert should probably come from %1
set toconvert=source file.mp3
set minsize=100
for %%a in ("%toconvert%") do (
    set target=%%~da%%~pa%%~na.wav
)

rem replace with a real call to ffmpeg
echo call ffmpeg -i "%toconvert%" "%target%"

set size=0
if exist "%target%" (
    for %%a in ("%target%") do (
        set size=%%~za
    )
)

if %size% LSS %minsize% (
    echo ERROR: The file is too small!
) ELSE (
    rem replace with a real call to del
    echo del "%toconvert%"
)
```